# Deriving Holder's Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

This is classwork:

Let $m,n > 1$, where $1/m + 1/n = 1$.  Fix $A > 0$ and have a function $f(x) = \frac{x^m}{m} + \frac{A^n}{nx^n}$ for $x > 0$.  Show that $f$ has a global minimum at $x = A^{1/m}$ and show that $A \leq \frac{x^m}{m} + \frac{A^n}{nx^n}$ for all $x, A > 0$.

I've taken the derivative and substituted $x = A^{1/m}$ to try and show it is a critical point but I'm unable to do so.  Hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

$$
f'(x) = x^{m-1} - \frac{A^n}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{x} \left( x^m - \frac{A^n}{x^n} \right)
$$
$$
(A^{1/m})^m = A
$$
$$
\left( \frac{A}{A^{1/m}} \right)^n = \left( A^{1 - 1/m} \right)^n = \left(A^{1/n}\right)^n = A
$$

since $1/m + 1/n = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, that was enough to show that it is a critical point.  Now I've taken the second derivative and shown that it is a local minimum; how would I prove it is the global min?

Comment: @user127473 Try showing that that is the only critical point.  I.e., for $x > 0$, $x^m - \frac{A^n}{x^n} = 0$ if and only if $x^{m+n} = A^n$; then take both sides to the power of $\frac{1}{mn}$ to get $x^{1/m + 1/n} = A^{1/n}$, so the only critical point is...